# Using WITH in MonetDB

Tags: sql, monetdb

I'm trying to execute the next query in MonetDB using "WITH":

```
with a as (select data_string from colombia.dim_tempo)
select 
 t.ano_mes 
,f.sg_estado
,f.cod_produto 
, sum(f.qtd_vendidas) as qtd_vendidas
, count(*) as fact_count
from colombia.fact_retail_market f, colombia.dim_tempo t
where f.cod_anomes = t.data_string 
and t.data_string in (a.data_string)
group by
 t.ano_mes 
,f.sg_estado 
,f.cod_produto ;
```

But always get this message:

[image]

What's wrong with the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause needs to be:

```sql
WHERE f.cod_anomes = t.data_string AND
      t.data_string IN (SELECT data_string FROM a)
```

That is, `IN` needs to be followed by a subquery against the CTE.

Comment: thank you! I think I understood the concept. The CTE acts like a "view".